# Is matrices $A$ form a field?

Tags: linear-algebra

Interpreting matrix entries in the field $\mathbb{F}_2$,

Is  matrices  $A = \begin{bmatrix}  0 &0 \\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$ forms a field ?

I thinks  No , because A is not invertible

Am i right/wrong?

Any hints/solution

Comment: In a field, only nonzero elements need an inverse. Try for two nonzero elements with zero product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right a field requires a multiplicative unity $1$ and an additive unity namely $0$ such that $0\ne 1$

Note that in a field, $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse but every other element has a multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 1):

In a field, every non-zero element must have a multiplicative inverse. Although it is true that $M_{2}(\mathbb{F})$ is not a field, the counter-example you give does not work because it is the zero matrix. Can you think of a non-zero two-by-two matrix that is not invertible?

Answer (score 1):

It is standard to define fields as rings with unity (which satisfy additional properties), which means that there must be some element $1$ such that $1$ is not the additive unity and $1\cdot x=x\cdot 1=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @coffeemath But the identity matrix is not an element of the singleton of the zero matrix.

Comment: Oh, I thought OP meent all 2 by 2 matrices entries in integers mod 2. Guess OP just meant the singe zero matrix.